# Understanding Reentrancy attacks

Tags: solidity, security, reentrant-attacks

I'm trying to understand the mechanism for a reentrancy attack, and how it might be mitigated. I'm looking at (for example) this scan result: https://de.fi/scanner/contract/0xab46a03d8B82F6f8551d05FfA5E071cAfB313e5D?chainId=arbi

I'd love to understand 1) Why/How does the WETHGateway Reentrancy vulnerability work?
2) What does it mean "No relevant code execution after reentrancy expression.", and what would the "bad" counterexample look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no vulnerability because the contract doesn't do anything after the external call.

There's a possibility of a re-entrancy bug only if you violate the **Checks-Effects-Interactions** pattern. As a rule of thumb, if in your function you don't mix these ones in a different order, then you're good.

In your example, the interaction (the external call) is at the end of the function, so you don't violate the pattern. That's what the analyzer means by saying there's no relevant code after the external call.

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question. Is there a way to avoid the scanner flagging it at all?

Comment: I don't know, you should ask the developers of the scanner.